# Again Perron Frobenius or not?

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be real $n$ by $n$ matrix with positive entries, and $I_n$ be the identity matrix of the same dimension.

Assume the spectral radius/Perron eigenvalue of $A$ is strictly less than 1.

Then one can prove $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $I_n-A$, hence $I_n-A$ is invertible, and this implies that the equation with unknown the vector $X$ *and* the real number $\alpha$:

$$AX + \alpha 1 = X$$ has a unique solution $(X,\alpha)$ up to multiplication (of both $X$ and $\alpha$) by a constant.

Can one prove that the coordinates of $X$ and $\alpha$ have the same sign ?

Comment: I think what you're asking is $\big(I-A\big)\mathbf x = \alpha \mathbf 1\implies \mathbf x = \alpha \big(I-A\big)^{-1}\mathbf 1= \alpha \big(\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k\big)\mathbf 1$ where the right hand side is a positive vector times $\alpha$ so all entries of $\mathbf x$ have the same sign as $\alpha$. I'm not sure how this relates to your title.

Comment: Thanks you very much @user8675309, I overlooked that simple argument !! I agree the relationship with my title was all but clear (if $A$ has spectral radius $1$, the solution is $\alpha=0$ and $X$ the Perron eigenvector of $A$).

Comment: @LeeMosher it is $I_n-A$ that is invertible, not $A$.